# Routing three URLs to single endpoint ? Using Flask and Jinja2

Tags: python, flask

I need to map three URLs to single view function.

```
@app.route('/items/', defaults={"item_name": "all", "status": "available"}, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/items/<item_name>/')
@app.route('/items/<item_name>/<status>')
def items_list(item_name, status):
    --- code goes here ----
```

First and last URL works. i.e., /items/ - item_name and status will have default values.
and /items/some_item_name/unavailable/ - it uses passed values.

When I try /items/some_item_name/ - it fails with this error "TypeError: item_list() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)", which I understand as function is expecting two parameters.
Is it not the correct way doing it? Why 'status' is not taking default value 'available'.
Because when we issue /items/, 'item_name' and 'status' takes default values. I was expecting same thing to happen when /items/some_item_name/ is used.

What is going wrong here? Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use default arguments in your function:

```
def items_list(item_name=None, status=None):
```

Comment: I am using defaults={"item_name": "all", "status": "available"}. Is it not applicable to all app.route?.

Comment: seems like no, your error says that takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given), if you do status=None it have to work.

Comment: It is working. Thanks. It is specific to URL, if we use '/items/', default values would be as given in 'defaults' dict. For '/items/<item_name>/', I used defaults dict as defaults={'status':'available'}.